# ReactJS Chat Websockets emits message twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, emit

I have a Chat component which works fine on the happy flow but when I go on another view (meaning I exit the chat component) and come back after that in the chat component, I get duplicates messages.

I placed an `console.log` into the function which is triggered by the `enter` event but it displays only once. However, the emit from inside trigger twice I think because on the server side (nodeJs) I get the data twice.

This is my code:

```
function Chat() {     
    let [chatInput, setChatInput] = useState('');   
    let [chatArea, setChatArea] = useState([]);     

    const handleOnChange = (e) => {
        setChatInput(e.target.value) 
    }

    useEffect(() => {                      
        const addTextMessage = (event) => {
            if (event.keyCode === 13 && chatInput.value !== '') {                
                event.preventDefault(); 
                
                socket.emit('chat', {
                    message: chatInput.value
                });                
                                                      
                setChatInput('');              
            }  
        }

        const chatInput = document.querySelector('.chat-input input');
        chatInput.addEventListener("keyup", addTextMessage, false);

        socket.on('chat', (data) => {
            setChatArea(prevInputState => (                    
                [...prevInputState, <section key={prevInputState.length}>{data.sender}: {data.message}</section>]
            ))                                     
        })  

        return () => {            
            chatInput.removeEventListener("keyup", addTextMessage, false);                
            socket.off('chat');        
        };  

    }, []);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>                                        
            <section className="chat-room">
                <div className="chat-area">
                    {chatArea}   
                </div>
                <div className="chat-input">
                    <input value={chatInput} onChange={handleOnChange} type="text" />
                </div>
            </section>         
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Contrary to what I was thinking, the issue was coming from my server side.

I have placed my `nsSocket.on('chat', (data) => {` by mistake inside another `nsSocket.on('` and after I extracted it outside, the problems were fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues I'm spotting:
**chatInput** is a string, It feels weird adding a event listener to a string. It might work.

`<input>` has a prop called onKeyUp that is probably very useful for you.

This might be much more simple and easier to find the issue if you still get duplicates:

```
const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("")
const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = useState([])

function trySendMessage(event) {
   // Send message if last key was ENTER and we got some text
   if (event.keyCode === 13 && userInput !== "") {
     event.preventDefault();
     socket.emit("chat", {
       message: chatInput,
     })
     setChatInput("");
   }
}

// This effect only changes the state
// Notice I'm not storing the rendered result in state,
// Instead I handle rendering below in the rendering section
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('chat', (newMessage) => setChatArea([...chatMessages, newMessage])
  return () => socket.off('chat')
}, [])

return (
   <section>
     {
       chatMessages.map(message => (
         <div key={message.id}>{message.name}: {message.body})</div>
       )
     }
     <input
       value={userInput}
       onChange={(e) => setUserInput(e.target.value)}
       onKeyUp={trySendMessage}
     />
   </section>
)
```

Comment: 'setUserInput' is not defined. Also I tried some parts of your code, it does not change anything.

Comment: In my code setUserInput is defined, see line 1. Add some console logs to see how many times useEffect is called. Another solution you can do is make sure there are no elements with the same id in chatMessages.

Comment: Yes but it's not available in the render method aparently.

Comment: Feel free to show your code with [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) :)